# How to remove text on pygame with a background without putting one again and again the background?

Tags: python, text, pygame, render

I have this:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
background_image = load_image('images/fondo.jpg') # previous declared function
FONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
text = FONT.render('Test', 1, (255, 255, 255))
a = screen.blit(text, (150,400))
```

And all i want is delete the render without deleting de background (i use fill, and it seems its only usable with colors, not images)

How do i Fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To effectively delete the text you have to blit over it with something else. So if you do something like:

```
screen.blit(background_image,(0,0))
```

when you want to delete text, the screen will look like the text never existed. It will also get rid of anything else you had on the screen so you'll have to re-blit desired effects again.

Comment: Then when people make a sprite, why they dont reblit?

Comment: because they use the sprite's draw function which essentially just blits the sprite's image at the sprite's location.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this post while researching how to do this cleanly for my own program.  Nothing I found seemed to consider all the possible cases. Came back to post the final result developed from the pieces I found.  The basic concept is to overwrite (blit over) the text with whatever is under it.  Or more accurately, whatever was there before blitting the text.

The documentation for the [blit](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) method of a [surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) shows that it has a signature of `blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0) -> Rect`.  The `dest` parameter is a coordinate, but will also use the top left corner of a `rect`.  To erase text from a surface, that optional area parameter (a `rect`) can be used.  Starting from your example code, a generic solution would be:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
background_image = load_image('images/fondo.jpg') # previous declared function
FONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
text = FONT.render('Test', 1, (255, 255, 255))
snapshot = screen.copy()  # take a copy without the text
a = screen.blit(text, (150,400))
pygame.display.update()  # show the screen at this state
do_stuff()
screen.blit(snapshot, a, a)  # Restore just the text area
pygame.display.update()  # show the screen without the text
```

That should always work as long as nothing in `do_stuff()` modifies the screen inside of the `a` rectangle that the text was placed in.

Assuming that `background_image` is a surface that was blitted to `screen` at `(0, 0)`, AND it covers the complete area of the `a` rectangle, the `sceen.copy()` can be ommitted, and the restore becomes
`screen.blit(background_image, a, a)`.  If background_image was blitted to `(DX, DY)`, that would change to `screen.blit(background_image, a, a.move(-DX, -DY))` to compensate for the offset.

Answer (score 0):

You could also turn the text into a sprite and remove it from your sprite groups once it has been added.
This will help if you just want to remove one or many text that is rendered text.

Example of how a sprite version of a text looks:

```
class Text(pg.sprite.Sprite): # <----> Sprite's name
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40) 
        self.image = font.render('Start', False, rpink)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


text = Text()
all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group() # <--- this is the sprite group
all_sprites.add(text) # <--> adding 'text' to the screen 
all_sprites.remove(text) # <--> removing text from the screen
```

No blitting involved or needed.